# Bootstrap nav tabs not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My nav tabs aren't working, though I checked the code like 1000 thimes. There is other code between the div col tags but that shouldn't make any difference.

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" data-tabs="tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#coursera" data-toggle="tab">Coursera</a></li>
            <li><a href="#research" data-toggle="tab">Research</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog" data-toggle="tab">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">

            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="coursera">
                <div class="col-sm-10"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="research">
                <div class="col-sm-10"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="blog">
                <div class="col-sm-10"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: are you seeing any errors in your developer console? Also, try putting those scripts in the `<head>` to see if they get picked up

Comment: make a fiddle, because your html works: https://jsbin.com/vutexubedu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see no errors in the console, and putting my scripts in the head doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: It turns out the col-sm classes inside my tab-panes do matter. When I replace them with other text, the tabs work fine. Whenever I reintroduce col classes, the tabs won't work. I'm pretty sure the col classes are legit code, as I use them elsewhere and they work fine. Is it just not possible to use the bootstrap grid system inside tab-panes? Anyone experiencing similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div class="container">
            <h3>Tabs With Dropdown Menu</h3>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#coursera" data-toggle="tab">Coursera</a></li>
                <li><a href="#research" data-toggle="tab">Research</a></li>
                <li><a href="#blog" data-toggle="tab">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>            
            <div class="tab-content">                
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="coursera">
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> coursera tab Div with class col-sm-10</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">coursera tab Div with class col-sm-2</div>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="research">
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> research tab Div with class col-sm-10</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">research tab Div with class col-sm-2</div>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="blog">
                    <div class="col-sm-10"> blog tab Div with class col-sm-10</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">blog tab Div with class col-sm-2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! I finally found the cause...

Apparently the titles just beneath the tabs were the problem. I had padding-top: 100px and margin-top: -100px for my titles in my custom css. Whenever I remove those, the tabs are working. I guess I should find another way to set up my anchors.